# Getting value from .data jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to put some caption in my images with lightbox plugin, it calls the caption with the function below:

```
setCaption: function () {
    var caption = $(plugin.current).data("caption");
    if(!!caption && caption.length > 0) {
        plugin.caption.fadeIn();
        $('p', plugin.caption).text(caption);
    }else{
         plugin.caption.hide();
    }
 },
```

I don't know the place in html that i have to type the caption to the function get it, could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Say the `plugin.current` element is a `<span>` then you do something like:

```
<span data-caption="My caption">Hello, World!</span>
```

The convention for `.data` will look for data attributes on an element. The preface `data-` is the indicator, and the suffix, `caption` is the name in this case, hence `data-caption`.